# Is it just me or is my node down?

Tags: internet, traffic, route, bgp

I find the www.doj.me very useful. I am looking for something like that but specifically for BGP Nodes. I want to write a script that tells the users if our Internet backbone is down, if if yes which backbone routes we are using. If I know the AS Numbers, can I query from open Looking Glass servers periodically for this information? What do I need to know to display this information?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily query existing looking glass servers and parse information about what they think about your backbone. See looking glasses:

http://www.bgp4.net/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:ipv4_looking_glasses

You should test them out and see what parameters they need. Usually a source and a destination..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free service from http://bgpmon.net/ to get e-mail notifications on BGP events for a specific prefix or ASN. Very useful and completely free.